# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Command Line Tool won't run on mac

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to learn how to deploy to AWS Elastic Beanstalk using a git repository and the elastic beans command line interface.

I've run through setup as per [instructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/GettingStarted.GetSetup-devtools.html). When I call: 
    eb --version

As per instructions [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP.sdlc.html#create_deploy_PHP.sdlc.deploy), it throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/deepthought/Cloud Drive/eb-cli/eb/macosx/python3/eb", line 17, in <module>
from scli import core
File "/Users/deepthought/Cloud Drive/eb-cli/eb/macosx/python3/scli/core.py", line 98
format(output_file), file=sys.stderr)
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've never used Python before and don't understand what I'm looking at.

How do I fix this error and run the Elastic Beanstalk command line interface?

Comment: Which version of Python are you running?

Comment: I'm using version 2.7.5

Comment: You should also check your ruby version and make sure that you have 1.8 or 1.9 to make it run (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-reference-get-started.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's picking up the Python 3 version of the `eb` tool. You need to add the Python 2.7 version to your path.

Comment: Thank you, this has sorted it. Now to figure out what to do with it. Cheers!

Comment: If you have both Python 2.7 and 3 is there a way to specify which Python will be used?