# How to delete a specific $PATH or change a path already set?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I have a similar problem than [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21613265/aws-elastic-beanstalk-command-line-tool-wont-run-on-mac):

I'm trying to learn how to deploy to AWS Elastic Beanstalk using a git repository and the elastic beans command line interface.
I'm using **Ubuntu**.

It seems that the cli should run on python 2.7 instead of python 3 (The aws cli folder has two versions, so I don understand why version 3 shouldn't be used).

I've set the path originally to:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/Rosamunda/mystuff/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.6.3/eb/linux/python3
```

After reading the information inside the link to the other conversation, I've tried then:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/Rosamunda/mystuff/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.6.3/eb/linux/python2.7
```

But the problem is still there. I believe because I should delete or deativate somehow the first link?

How may I do that?

Comment: What platform are you on and which shell do you use?

Comment: Ubuntu Linux. I've updated the question.